# Run PowerShell script in .net core 2.1

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core, windows-server

I am currently trying to set up a PowerShell script call from an API developed in .NET Core 2.1
For the moment I am running a simple script that creates a text file

My script => `New-Item -Path "C:\Users\my-pc\Desktop\file1.txt" -ItemType File`

Calling this script works perfectly when I run my API project in debug.
The problem comes once I deploy my site on my Windows 2016 server. If I call the API containing the call to my script then the script does not run, I tried running the script directly in PowerShell and it works fine.
Below is the code used to run the script, if anyone has a solution I am a taker.

```
var currentFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var defaultScript = Path.Combine(currentFolder, "script.txt");
var pathTempo = Path.Combine(folderWebScraping, "temp");
var contentScript = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(defaultScript);

Logger.Info("--------------------------");
Logger.Info(contentScript);
Logger.Info("--------------------------");

var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddScript(contentScript, true);
var result = powerShell.Invoke();
```

Thanks Quentin

Comment: Probably a permissions issue (does the user account running the script have access to write to `\users\my-pc`?). Check `powerShell.HadErrors` and consume the `powerShell.Streams.Error` collection on failure

Comment: Running commands is dangerous especially if commands are created or modified by users. If you want to create a file, use System.IO instead.